# OpenCL set and clear bit of unsigned long long number in kernel

Tags: opencl

I use the follow code to set and clear bit of unsigned long long in a kernel void in OpenCL

```
A1 |= 1ll << 2 * i;  // i = 9 , set bit 18 =1, A1 long long int
A1 &= ~(1ll << 2 * i + 1); //clear bit 19 = 0
```

My code run well in CUDA, but in OpenCL, it has error CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY in buildprogram.
but if i use

```
A1 |= 1 << 2 * i;  // i = 9 , set bit 18 =1, A1 long long int
A1 &= ~(1 << 2 * i + 1); //clear bit 19 = 0
```

it run fine but result wrong because it can't set bit of long long number.
Can you help me!

Answer (score 1):

The data type `long long` is a reserved keyword for future extensions in OpenCL 2.0 (and probably in 2.1 too). You cannot use it, as there is no implementation possible.

See: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/reservedDataTypes.html